# Step through MonoGame source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, monogame

Is there a way to step through MonoGame source code while debugging (like with the .NET Framework) without having to compile MonoGame myself? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Do you have pdb files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481677/how-to-get-visual-studio-to-step-into-third-party-assemblies

Comment: @CodeCaster No, they didn't come with the installer and I couldn't find them anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Visual Studio requires a successful compilation to enable stepping through code.

Comment: because a successful compilation generates intermediate language (IL) which pdb files use to map to the original source code files.